# Git в IDEA. Удаление ответвления

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Подскажите доходчивее, как удалить ветку с комитами `5.2` `5.3` `5.3` ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

*Как удалить ветку **git** в **IDE idea**?*

Правой кнопкой мыши по ветке **`Branch 'branchName'` ⇒ `Delete`**

---

См. дополнительно: [smartgit](https://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/) - кросс-платформенное приложение. Ну и, конечно, консоль никто не отменял.

Answer (score 0):

Просто удалите ветку

```
git branch -D name
```

Comment: При команде  git branch - показывает только основную ветку * master.

Comment: Значит у вас другая ветка запушена в ремоут, а локально ее нет. Git branch показывает только локальные ветки. Попробуйте git branch -a , чтобы увидеть все ветки. Для удаление ремоут ветки можно использовать git push origin --delete branch_name

Comment: https://clip2net.com/s/3Uv9ypo   Подскажите а дальше?

Comment: @РусланТопольский вам показывает, что существует всего 2 ветки. 1 локальная мастер и 1 ремоут мастер. В чем проблема ? На вашем скрине ветки расходятся потому, что ваш локальный мастер не совпадает с ремоут мастером. Вам нужно либо взять изменения с ремоут мастера, либо запушить свой локальный мастер в ремоут.

Comment: Ээээээ ,можно попроще. ну вот прям чтобы совсем... https://clip2net.com/s/3UwslEr При обновлении проекта - вот так по кругу...